# Clip Raster with Shapefile GDAL API

Tags: raster, gdal, clip, gdalwarp, geos

I am trying to clip a raster using a polygon an GDAL. The following code is running without an error but the ouputimage is all zeros. All files are in the same CRS. Is there a way to use GdalWarp with Cutline?

```
  const char* inputPath = "input.tif";
  const char* outputPath = "output.tif";
 
  //clipper Polygon
  auto w_read_filenamePoly = "Polygon.shp";
  char* read_filenamePoly = new char[w_read_filenamePoly.length() + 1];
  wcstombs(read_filenamePoly, w_read_filenamePoly.c_str(), w_read_filenamePoly.length() + 1);

  GDALDataset* hSrcDS; 
  GDALDataset* hDstDS;

  GDALAllRegister();
  hSrcDS =(GDALDataset *) GDALOpen(inputPath, GA_Update);
  hDstDS = (GDALDataset*)GDALOpen(outputPath, GA_Update);
 
  const char* proj = hSrcDS->GetProjectionRef();
  const char* proj2 = hDstDS->GetProjectionRef();

  //clipper Layer
  GDALDataset* poDSClipper;
  poDSClipper = (GDALDataset*)GDALOpenEx(read_filenamePoly, GDAL_OF_UPDATE, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  Assert::IsNotNull(poDSClipper);
  delete[]read_filenamePoly;
  OGRLayer* poLayerClipper;
  poLayerClipper = poDSClipper->GetLayerByName("Polygon");
  int numClip = poLayerClipper->GetFeatureCount();

  //get my geometry as OGRPolygon
  std::vector<OGRFeature*> vecClipFeature;
  OGRFeature* feat;
  while ((feat = poLayerClipper->GetNextFeature()) != NULL)
  {
    vecClipFeature.push_back(feat);
  }
  OGRGeometry* geom = vecClipFeature.at(0)->GetGeometryRef();
  OGRPolygon *clipPoly = geom->toPolygon();

  //setup warp options
  GDALWarpOptions* psWarpOptions = GDALCreateWarpOptions();
  psWarpOptions->hSrcDS = hSrcDS;
  psWarpOptions->hDstDS = hDstDS;
  psWarpOptions->nBandCount = 1;
  psWarpOptions->panSrcBands = (int *) CPLMalloc(sizeof(int) * psWarpOptions->nBandCount);
  psWarpOptions->panSrcBands[0] = 1;
  psWarpOptions->panDstBands = (int*)CPLMalloc(sizeof(int) * psWarpOptions->nBandCount);
  psWarpOptions->panDstBands[0] = 1;
  psWarpOptions->pfnProgress = GDALTermProgress;
  psWarpOptions->hCutline = clipPoly;
  
  
  // Establish reprojection transformer.
  psWarpOptions->pTransformerArg = GDALCreateGenImgProjTransformer(hSrcDS,proj, hDstDS, proj2, FALSE, 0.0, 1);
  psWarpOptions->pfnTransformer = GDALGenImgProjTransform;
 
  GDALWarpOperation oOperation;
  oOperation.Initialize(psWarpOptions);
  oOperation.ChunkAndWarpImage(0, 0, GDALGetRasterXSize(hDstDS), GDALGetRasterYSize(hDstDS));
  GDALDestroyGenImgProjTransformer(psWarpOptions->pTransformerArg);
  GDALDestroyWarpOptions(psWarpOptions);
  GDALClose(hDstDS);
  GDALClose(hSrcDS);
```

Comment: GdalWarp is gdalwarp https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html in Python and supports also cutline. You can find usage examples from the GDAL Python tests https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_gdalwarp_lib.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of a question on SO. There are many pitfalls when using the C++ interface.

```cpp
#include <gdal/gdal.h>
#include <gdal/gdal_priv.h>
#include <gdal/gdalwarper.h>
#include <gdal/ogrsf_frmts.h>

int main() {
  const char *inputPath = "input.tif";
  const char *outputPath = "output.tif";

  // clipper Polygon
  // THIS FILE MUST BE IN PIXEL/LINE COORDINATES or otherwise one should
  // copy the function gdalwarp_lib.cpp:TransformCutlineToSource()
  // from GDAL's sources
  // It is expected that it contains a single polygon feature
  const char *read_filenamePoly = "cutline.json";

  GDALDataset *hSrcDS;
  GDALDataset *hDstDS;

  GDALAllRegister();
  auto poDriver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName("GTiff");
  hSrcDS = (GDALDataset *)GDALOpen(inputPath, GA_ReadOnly);

  hDstDS = (GDALDataset *)poDriver->CreateCopy(
    outputPath, hSrcDS, 0, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
  // Without this step the cutline is useless - because the background
  // will be carried over from the original image
  CPLErr e = hDstDS->GetRasterBand(1)->Fill(0);

  const char *src_srs = hSrcDS->GetProjectionRef();
  const char *dst_srs = hDstDS->GetProjectionRef();

  // clipper Layer
  GDALDataset *poDSClipper;
  poDSClipper = (GDALDataset *)GDALOpenEx(
    read_filenamePoly, GDAL_OF_UPDATE, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  auto poLayerClipper = poDSClipper->GetLayer(0);
  auto geom = poLayerClipper->GetNextFeature()->GetGeometryRef();

  // setup warp options
  GDALWarpOptions *psWarpOptions = GDALCreateWarpOptions();
  psWarpOptions->hSrcDS = hSrcDS;
  psWarpOptions->hDstDS = hDstDS;
  psWarpOptions->nBandCount = 1;
  psWarpOptions->panSrcBands =
    (int *)CPLMalloc(sizeof(int) * psWarpOptions->nBandCount);
  psWarpOptions->panSrcBands[0] = 1;
  psWarpOptions->panDstBands =
    (int *)CPLMalloc(sizeof(int) * psWarpOptions->nBandCount);
  psWarpOptions->panDstBands[0] = 1;
  psWarpOptions->pfnProgress = GDALTermProgress;
  psWarpOptions->hCutline = geom;

  // Establish reprojection transformer.
  psWarpOptions->pTransformerArg = GDALCreateGenImgProjTransformer(
    hSrcDS, src_srs, hDstDS, dst_srs, TRUE, 1000, 1);
  psWarpOptions->pfnTransformer = GDALGenImgProjTransform;

  GDALWarpOperation oOperation;
  oOperation.Initialize(psWarpOptions);
  oOperation.ChunkAndWarpImage(
    0, 0, GDALGetRasterXSize(hDstDS), GDALGetRasterYSize(hDstDS));
  GDALDestroyGenImgProjTransformer(psWarpOptions->pTransformerArg);
  GDALDestroyWarpOptions(psWarpOptions);
  GDALClose(hDstDS);
  GDALClose(hSrcDS);
}
```